# Combating Fallout 4 radiation illness in survival

Tags: fallout-4

Before I start, let me make it clear that I'm not talking about radiation *sickness*, but rather about contracting illnesses from being irradiated in survival mode.

- To be succinct, is it normal to contract illnesses from standing in
  radiation (and not a cause of one of my mods)?
- If so, can this be negated with the Ghoulish perk or a hazmat suit/rad-x?
- If there's no way to negate it, can anyone point me to a mod that does? Its' pretty immersion-breaking to get random illnesses (namely parasites, infections, and weakness) from a few seconds of gamma radiation, *especially* if even being "ghoulish" doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Hi Zoraal, welcome to Arqade! Can you give an overview of the mods that could potentially cause the contraction of illnesses from standing in irradiated water?

Answer (score 2):

- **It is unclear whether standing in irradiated water in vanilla Fallout 4 survival mode causes illnesses *in particular***:

  The FO4 Wikia only notes that

  > swimming in irradiated water<sup>*</sup>

  increases the risk of contracting an illness. 

  In addition, a Steam thread comment describes how

  > "Exposure" can cause illness too, this includes any and all radiation
  >   sources, as well as rain.<sup>✝</sup>

  This claim is repeated [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/364040961447187611/?ctp=2#c364040961449633713) (by the same user).

  Therefor, I assume that the contraction of diseases by standing in water is likely 
  (but not certainly) implemented by one of your mods.
- **Even so, wearing a hazmat suit, or consuming Rad-X, should be 
  able to influence it, since both reduce your rads or rad absorption, making you 
  less prone to contamination**. Whether they can negate the direct effects on standing in water, depends on the radiation levels of the water and the duration. **The Ghoulish perk won't decrease the amount of radiation you absorb altogether, but will return a percentage of it as health**.

  I suggest you look [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/246098/is-it-possible-for-the-player-character-to-become-immune-to-radiation-poisoning) for additional information on gaining radiation 
  resistance, and [here](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Radiation_Resistance#Fallout_4) for an overview of its (percentual) mechanism.

  Note as well, that Fallout 4 most likely has a Rad Resistance cap, like (some of) its predecessors:

  > In Fallout, Radiation Resistance can go as high as 100%, which is
  >   needed to survive The Glow. In Fallout 2, it is capped at 95%; in
  >   Fallout: New Vegas, however, it is capped at 85%.<sup>○</sup>
- **As for your third sub-question, as *complete* immunity to radiation may not be attainable, there are enough ways to make you stop worrying about its effects**. Lead plated Power Armor, the Mysterious Serum, Hazmat suits, the Robes of Atom's Devoted all significantly increase your resistance.

<sup>* https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Condition#Illness

✝ https://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/2906376154334607210/#c2906376154334744788

○ https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Radiation_Resistance#Notes</sup>

Answer (score 0):

To combat radiation illness in Fallout 4 you can go to diamond city and visit the doctor, who will cure you of radiation poisoning. You can also build up a resistance by getting the "aquaboy" perk. This allows you to not be affected by radiation in water.